# How do diagnose a drop in frame rate?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am developing a game in which creatures are crossing a road and may occasionally get "splatted" by a passing car. I am continuously displaying the frame rate on screen. When the game starts the frame rate is typically 20-25fps, but when my creatures get splatted and their bitmaps swap to their splatted state, the frame rate plummets down to around 4 per second. This is strange as the "splatted" bitmaps I'm drawing are smaller than the bitmaps for my creatures in their alive state.

The problem could, I guess, be all sorts of things - for example there are assorted routines in the update_game_physics() code that behave differently. But my question is - how could I diagnose the cause? Are their tools or techniques that could help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, profilers are tools that can help you for that.
This [question provides a list of some profilers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14762/please-recommend-a-java-profiler)

Comment: Just wondering why this answer got voted down. Don't profilers do that job?

Comment: I guess you should give a link or reference to profilers along with your answer, that might be the reason for the downvote.

Comment: OK, fair enough, will do. Although a comment on my question would have been more constructive.